# Why ECONNRESET error is coming in POSTMAN while making a NODEJS request

Tags: node.js, express

I have written a simple request response code in NODEJS but there is no response in return of the request is there .

The code for my app.js(Server file) is

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors') 
const paymentroute = require('./routes/paymentRoutes');

 const app = express();




 app.use(cors);


app.use("/api",paymentroute);

app.listen(3100,()=>{

  console.log(`listening to port 3100`);
})
```

The code for my req and res is

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

// const  { checkout } = require('../controllers/paymentController');




router.post("/checkout",(req,res) => { 

  console.log("this function is called ")
  return res.json({success:"true"})
});


module.exports =  router;
```

Even the console.log inside the res function is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Just change  app.use(cors); to  app.use(cors());

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const paymentroute = require('./routes/paymentRoutes');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use('/api', paymentroute);

app.listen(3100, () => {
    console.log(`listening to port 3100`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a connection-related issue often related to a networking issue caused by a Virtual Private Network (VPN) that in some cases is required by some API services or, in other cases, prevents you to reach an API service.

The issue seems to be a combo of having the **no-cache header** enabled and a **request URL length** over 64 characters. If the issue persists after doing this solution then try to upgrade to the latest version of Postman.